# How do I return an http status code in an AngularJS single page application?

Tags: angularjs, seo, single-page-application, http-status-codes

I have an AngularJS single page application used to display short-living resources, with an url like /auction/103. However, when the resource is no longer available, I wish to remove that page from the index of search engines. Thus, I need to return the status code 410 or 404 when a search engine crawler passes by.

However, how do I do this with a single page application where the page is not rendered on the server?

Comment: Unfortunately the provided information is not enough to answer on your question. Here are some questions which might help you compile a whole picture and solve your issue(s): how do you communicate with the server? What do you use to load parts of the pages of your SAP? Are you using $http angularjs service? What are you using to handle states when you switch between pages in your SAP (I am hinting to routing). What do you have on the server side? Is it ASP.Net? Thank you.

Comment: I am not talking about the server communication with $http, I am talking about the status code which can be served to a search engine which requests the page.

Comment: if you were using Prerender, can you update your question to reflect your were talking about a site using prerender? (prerender is not mentioned, and this is not related to angular)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you use Prerender for SEO, you can specify a meta tag which make Prerender return an http status code to the search engine crawler: https://prerender.io/server#http-headers.

```
<meta name="prerender-status-code" content="404">
```

I have created a Plunker to illustrate this using AngularJS: http://plnkr.co/edit/Z0HdMd.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt get your question
But , if you're using $http.post org $http.get , to get what ever data you want , this $http request can return a promise and that promise has http statuses. like this

```
      $scope.yourFunction = function($http){
         var promise = $http.post('YourURL',{Your data to send});
             promise.then(function(msg){
                console.log('promise', msg.status);
             // now you can see your status in your console !
            })
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

@Jan, I don't know how familiar you are with SPAs and SEO, but the bottom line is they really don't work well together. Basically, search engines run a headless browser on their crawlers without running much JavaScript. Therefore, if your application is truly a SPA, you're really only serving the index file on a hard page load, and that's all that will get crawled by search engines. There is hope though: [Check this out](http://blog.alexmaccaw.com/seo-in-js-web-apps)... although it's probably a bit more than you bargained for

Comment: You can also use [Prerender](http://prerender.io) which renders your page with Javascript and serves a static version to the crawlers passing by.

Answer (score 0):

Angular being a client side library does not have the capability to set/send a `404` or any other header/status-codes. That is server's job.

When you make a call to your server for `/auction/103`, the server will respond back with your `index.html` file written in angular with a `200` status code. The angular library then generates the content you see. At this point even if angular realizes that there is no route for the requested resource `/auction/103`, the server has already sent out the headers and the status code, so those can't change. The only thing angular can do is to show the `404` page if you have set it.

The fix however is not easy. As other answers have pointed already, you can use other service providers to handle this, but to handle it on server side, you will need to catch the request, decide if the page exists or not, then send either an `index.html` page or a `404.html` page. A very crude example from my node's server.js file is below.

```
// Send every request to `handleRequest()` method which determines if the requested resource exists.
// E.g. I will check if /auction/103 exists in database and will return false if it does not.
app.get('*', function (request, response) {
  if (handleRequest(request) !== false) {
    response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'))
  } else {
    response.status(404)
    response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '404.html'))
  }
})
```

You of course can edit this logic to better suit your needs, but the gist is to determine the existence of resource on the server itself.